# Prevent Docker container to exit

Tags: docker, docker-entrypoint

I'm start to dockerize a Linux Application and to do that I wrote a Dockerfile that:

- Extract the application TAR file into a directory.
- Execute the "entrypoint.sh"

the "entrypoint.sh":

- Check if the application is already installed.
- If the application is not installed, execute the installation script.

After that the container stops because the application run a background service.

Since I'm relative new to dockerize application, how can I prevent the container to stop?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: your can review [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41555884/docker-what-does-docker-run-restart-always-actually-do#:~:text=Restart%20policies&text=Always%20restart%20the%20container%20regardless,current%20state%20of%20the%20container.) docker run --always

Comment: Make its `CMD` run a process that doesn't exit.  The container will exit exactly when its main process does.  The main process needs to run in the foreground.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to keep Docker container running after starting services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25775266/how-to-keep-docker-container-running-after-starting-services)

Answer (score 4):

Use `ENTRYPOINT ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]` at the end of your `Dockerfile`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to detach the session so that it can run in the background:

`docker run -dt image`